# Forwarding website request via Vnet-2-Vnet tunnel in Azure

Tags: azure, request, azure-virtual-network

Can someone please help me with this Azure solution.

Scenario:

> I have VM1 in VNet in Azure (VNet1) and a VM2 in another VNET (VNet2).
>   I have created a VNet-2-VNet tunnel between these two and I verified
>   that it works properly. I have a website that is only reachable from
>   the VM2 in VNet2 via VPN S2S tunnel. If I try telnet from VM1 to VM2
>   it works. If I try to browse the HTTPS (443) site from the VM2 it
>   works.

What I need to do:

> I need to be able to browse the website directly on VM1. My guess is
>   that I will have to set up some routing that traffic from VM1 will hop
>   to VM2 and from there send the request to the website, or something.
>   So far nothing I've tried works.

If you need any more information I will fill in the blanks.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft Azure support and the helpdesk person told me that the only way how I could achieve this would be to:

1. Have the VNET2VNET tunnel between my VNET1 and VNET2
2. Have the Site2Site VPN connection between my VNET2 and the on-premises Website
3. Create a UDR on my VNET1 to forward traffic from subnet in VNET1 to the destination over my Virtual Appliance (VM2 in VNET2)
4. Enable BGP on both of my VNETs, **and** also enable BGP on the on-premises network

This was unfortunately not possible for me, because I only manage the 2 VNETs for client and the on-premises network is managed solely by client and he didn't want to enable it. Luckily I have one other option how to acomplish the connection. I will need to move the VM that needs access from VNET1 to VNET2 and from there contact the on-premises site directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you set vnet-to-vent between Vnet1 and Vnet2, then set site-to-site between vnet2 and web Vnet, and you want to community Vnet1 and Web Vnet?

If I understand it correctly, for now, Azure does **not** support this, because there is **no** derived transitive relationship.

As a workaround, we can configure VM2 to forward traffic to Web Vnet, make VM2 work as a router.

---

Update:

We can install RRAS on it, and configure NAT for it, work like this:

[image]

More information about it, please refer to this [blog](http://techgenix.com/using-windows-server-nat-router/).

---

**Update2:**

The best way to achieve it, we should create a VPN between web net and VNet2.

Comment: Well the Vnet-to-Vnet (between Vnet1 and Vnet2) is already setup and working and site-to-site (between Vnet2 and web Vnet) is also setup and working. So yeah, that was my first idea to set up the VM2 to route traffic from Vnet1 to Web Vnet, but I don't know how to set it up, so if you have some advice, I would welcome it very much.

Comment: @TadeášBucha Linux VM or Windows VM?

Comment: @TadeášBucha We can install RRAS in it, work it as an NAT router, here a blog about it, please refer to [it](http://techgenix.com/using-windows-server-nat-router/).

Comment: Well since I haven't configured NAT router so far, the guide doesn't help much, since the scenario described is a little bit different.

Comment: @TadeášBucha that just an example, we can use RRAS to route network traffic to another IP address.

Comment: Understood, however it doesn't offer me much help with my configuration, since the configurations I've seen in videos/blogs use external and internal network interface and route traffic from one to another. I need to route the traffic withing one network interface from one source to destination using that machine.

Comment: @TadeášBucha I see, I will do some test in my lab, If I get something new, i will update to you:)

Comment: @TadeášBucha Sorry, it seems we can't use RRAS just route one ip address to vnet2. As a work around, we can create a RRAS server in VM2, and connect web net client to VM2, same as a point-to-point VPN. hope that helps:)

Comment: @TadeášBuchat Thank you for your share, that is a good way to achieve it, just create VPN between them, I will update it to my answer, thank you for your share again:)